# Sharing internet connection between windows xp and Mac

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, internet, home-networking, internet-connection

I have one windows XP and Mac/Snow Leopard. I would like to share internet connection. I have one data card, which I would like to plug in in the windows machine and be able to access internet connection as well as share files on Mac. I think there are windows in-built utility and setting etc to share ICS and set-up wireless etc..

but the process depends from windows version to version etc..which I find messy and confusing ..Aren't there some simple 3rd party lightweight utility to share a selected internet connection and create a wireless network..which works across different platforms too.

any alternative to "virtual router" for windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

[Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/). Really easy, really stable, works *very* well.

If you are a student, the pro version is free for you. But I've been using the free version for a long time. No nag-screen, no ads, nothing. It just works.

(Don't worry about the promo on their page, the free version will share everything to anything.)

Comment: I don't think that Connectify works on windows XP..I think it is for Windows 7..(??)

Comment: Ad-hoc mode is supported. That works for Snow leopard <-> XP as far as I know.